# compare and replace common words with place-holder

Tags: awk

I am trying to compare 2 text files and the awk seems to be working:

```
# cat remove.txt
test
junk
trash
unwanted
bad
worse

# cat corpus.txt
this is a test message to check if bad words are removed correctly. The second line may or may not have unwanted words. The third line also need not be as clean as first and second line.
There can be paragraphs in the text corpus and the entire file should be checked for trash.
```

This command is working as expected But I need to replace the words with XXX instead of simply removing it.

```
awk -v RS='[[:space:]]+' 'FNR == NR {seen[$1]; next} 
!($1 in seen) {ORS=RT; print}' remove.txt corpus.txt
```

Output:

```
this is a message to check if words are removed correctly. The second line may or may not have words. The third line also need not be as clean as first and second line.
There can be paragraphs in the text corpus and the entire file should be checked for trash.
```

The expected output will look something like this...

```
this is a xxx message to check if xxx words are removed correctly. The second line may or may not have xxx words. The third line also need not be as clean as first and second line.
There can be paragraphs in the text corpus and the entire file should be checked for trash.
```

If I remove the common words, there is no way to know where it used to be. (need place-holders) This is around 400MB english corpus that may contain non-english unicode characters.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You may use this `gnu awk`:

```sh
awk -v RS='[[:space:]]+' 'FNR == NR {seen[$1]; next} $1 in seen {$1 = "xxx"} {ORS=RT} 1' remove.txt corpus.txt

this is a xxx message to check if xxx words are removed correctly. The second line may or may not have xxx words. The third line also need not be as clean as first and second line.
There can be paragraphs in the text corpus and the entire file should be checked for trash.
```

Important changes are:

```sh
$1 in seen {$1 = "xxx"}  # if word is from remove list then set it to xxx
{ORS=RT}                 # set output record separator as RT
1                        # print each record
```

Answer (score 2):

With your shown samples, could you please try following. Written and tested with GNU `awk` and taking OP's shown code to fix this.

```
awk -v RS='[[:space:]]+' '
FNR == NR{
  seen[$1]
  next
}
{
  $1=($1 in seen?"XXX":$1)
  ORS=RT
  print
}
' remove.txt corpus.txt
```

***Explanation:*** Adding detailed explanation for above.

```
awk -v RS='[[:space:]]+' '     ##Starting awk program from here and setting RS as spaces here.
FNR == NR{                     ##Checking condition which will be TRUE when remove.txt is being read.
  seen[$1]                     ##Creating seen with index of 1st field.
  next                         ##next will skip all further statements from here.
}
{
  $1=($1 in seen?"XXX":$1)     ##Checking condition if $1 is in seen then set it to XXX else keep $1.
  ORS=RT                       ##Setting ORS value as RT.
  print                        ##Printing current line here.
}
' remove.txt corpus.txt        ##Mentioning Input_file names here.
```